# Deep frying - taste difference in saturated vs. unsaturated oil

Tags: flavor, deep-frying

In [one of my questions](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/6419/24980) I received answers that indicated using more saturated (Animal) fats would extend the life of my deep frying oil.

However - given proper maintenance / cleaning / good oil - how can the taste difference between fries made in saturated vs unsaturated oil be described?

(I use fries in the question as they are fairly neutral in flavor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fries cooked in animal fat will taste distinctly different than those fried in a neutral vegetable oil. They will be much richer in flavor and may make you weep with joy.

If you haven't had them, you must stop what you're doing and make some duck fat fries.

Here is a good recipe: http://hecooksshecooks.net/2009/03/duck-fat-french-fries/

Comment: Yessir. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the fats and the oils used. Vegetable and canola oil are mostly neutral in flavor, but you can just as easily cook in olive oil which would add flavor to your fries. Animal fats can certainly add flavor to the food you're cooking as well, usually for the best (mmmm . . . pork lard)!

Comment: Typical (virgin) olive oil is far below the smoke point required for deep-frying.  You could use the refined stuff - but that won't actually add much flavour.

Comment: @Aaronut I don't think it's *that* far below, but would probably not work well for deep frying . . . anyway, sesame oil has a higher smoke point, and would certainly add flavor (overpowering, really). My point was that all oils that you could fry in aren't flavorless.

Comment: You're right, it's not *that* far below, but when you're talking about smoke points, small differences matter a great deal (the oil either smokes or it doesn't).  Unrefined sesame oil is also too low (refined is high enough, but again, isn't as flavourful as pure sesame oil).  See this [list of common smoke points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_point).  I certainly don't disagree with the gist of your answer, I just felt it necessary to point out in case somebody saw this and decided to attempt a deep-fry in extra-virgin olive oil.

Comment: You cannot fry with olive oil! No ifss about it. Grapeseed oil is a good smoke point, around 415-420. EVOO is 380. 350-365 is what you need to fry. Just won't work.