# How long can you store used cooking oil

Tags: oil

How long can you store used cooking oil then re-use it? I deep fried a turkey one year ago and have had it refrigerated since.

Comment: See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3014. That other question answers "how many times can I reuse frying oil". The duplicate target asks "for what period of time can I store once-used frying oil".

Comment: I closed as a duplicate of a newer question, because this one has not gathered any good answers, maybe the newer one will fare better.

Answer (score -1):

Does the oil smell anywhere near rancid ?  You sure you had it in the fridge, not the freezer ?

Pure fat in the fridge keep a long, long, time... but I suspect some turkey juice got into it... would be fat-coated and not exposed to oxidation though...